# Periodic event in popcorn.js

Tags: javascript, popcornjs

How can popcorn.js be configured to emit event every time there's update in time of the video? Should I just use the timeupdate event of the video element then?

Currently, I could only setup event at a specific start time:

```
var p = Popcorn( "#video" )
      // play the video
      .play()
      // set the volume to zero
      .volume( 0 )
      .code({
        start: 1,
        end: 3,
        onStart: function( options ) {         
          document.getElementById( "test1" ).innerHTML = "Yes";
        },
        onEnd: function( options ) {
          document.getElementById( "test1" ).innerHTML = "No";
        }
     })
```

Comment: The first step is always to check the documentation: http://mozilla.github.io/popcorn-docs/events/ Even with excellent examples. Is http://jsfiddle.net/popcornjs/BcaGB/ what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but it seems that popcorn.js is not used. The fiddle was utilizing timeupdate of video element.

Comment: Oh, right you are.

Comment: Actually `timeupdate` is the closest event you are seeking and link posted by @ippi is also posted in official docs of popcorn js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official Docs](http://mozilla.github.io/popcorn-docs/events/#timeupdate) it says you capture event everytime the player time is updated

```
var pop = Popcorn("#video");

pop.on("timeupdate", function( e ) {
    console.log( "timeupdate fired!");
});

pop.play();
```

Comment: Great! Quick question: if I replace on by listen, it works as well. What are the difference between them (.on and .listen)?

Comment: They have deprecated the `.listen` method . Check the official github code https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js/blob/master/popcorn.js#L2663 . So it is advised to use `.on`